# What are these black masses floating on my pool?

Tags: species-identification, algae

I've been cleaning them for some time. At first I thought it was some kind of synthetic material, but when I took one with my fingers it disintegrated into filaments. I placed another under my usb microscope and they appear to be an aggregate of green tubular bodies.

[image: black mass inder microscope]

They grow (appear) from one day to another, only 1-2mm diameter. My best guess is that they are some kind of algae, but I'm lost to find exactly what. I live in the south of Spain, the pool is treated with chlorine, in a well illuminated zone. There are no other algae growing, and the area is urbanized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong kingdom. After much searching I asked myself: are those eggs? Silly me, of course they are. I should have thought it from the start. Mosquitoes plant their eggs on water over night. I was confused because in the past I've never seen the eggs, only the larvae and the pupae in the water. So, that's what I have every morning floating in my pool, groups of mosquito eggs.
http://animalia-life.club/other/mosquito-eggs.html